# Examples of cardinals such that $a>b$ and $a<a^b$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality, examples-counterexamples, cardinals

In a test where the topic was cardinal arithmetic, one student claimed that $a^b=a$ for any infinite cardinals such that $a>b$ (and used this claim in some computations). It is clear that $a\le a^b$, but it is possible that the inequality is strict.

Coincidentally, the student got the correct result, since all cardinals in this problem were [beth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number) and for such numbers you cannot get a counterexample. (If $a=2^c$ where $c\ge b$, then we get $a^b=2^{c\cdot b} = 2^c = a$.)

The simplest counterexample I was able to come up with was 
$$\aleph_\omega<\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}.$$
Indeed we have $\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\omega)=\aleph_0$, so we get from [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28set_theory%29) that
$$\aleph_\omega<\aleph_\omega^{\operatorname{cf}(\aleph_\omega)}=\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}.$$

Are there some other simple (interesting, insightful) counterexamples to this claim? I.e., some other examples of infinite cardinals such that $$a>b\text{ and }a<a^b.$$ Some comments on an example I suggested - for example, if it can be simplified or generalized - are welcome as well. (To make things easier, let us work in ZFC; i.e., we assume that Axiom of Choice holds.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\sf GCH$, these are the only counterexamples you will find. And since it is consistent with $\sf ZFC$, you can't do much better.

To see this is the case, note that $\sf GCH$ implies that for all regular $\kappa$, $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa$.

If there is some place the countinuum hypothesis fails, it will be the counterexample you want anyway.

Comment: I will add link to the following post in connection with the equality you mentioned under GCH: [Why do $2^{\lt\kappa}=\kappa$ and $\kappa^{\lt\kappa}=\kappa$ when the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis holds?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/91011) (This also seems related to some extent: [Why $\kappa^{<\kappa}=2^{<\kappa}$, if $\kappa$ is a regular and limit cardinal?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/249776))

Comment: Just checking whether I understand this correctly - by saying that "these are the only counterexamples under GCH" you mean that if I have such an example (and assume GCH), then $a$ has to be singular cardinal?

Comment: And if GCH fails that means $\kappa<\kappa^+<2^\kappa$ and I get $(\kappa^+)^\kappa=\kappa$, which gives a counterexample. (This is from $2^\kappa\le\kappa^\kappa \le (\kappa^+)^\kappa \le (2^\kappa)^\kappa = 2^\kappa$.) Is this what you meant in the sentence about place where GCH fails?

Comment: Yes to both questions.